# Device not showing up in android studio for mac

Tags: android

I have a note 8, that was showing up in android studio some months ago. Now the device does not show as a potential device to boot my app. USB debugging has been turned on. The default USB configuration has been set to transfer files. I even tried wiping the device, it didn't work. The device doesn't show up with android file transfer either. Although the phone does charge when connected to the computer. I'm not sure what to do about this, any suggestions?

Comment: Try with installing PDAnet. Hope it will work. 

http://pdanet.co/help/mac.php

Comment: i tried handshaker, that only works over wifi, which doesn't help given my current problem

Comment: Try with PDA net it will solve your problem I hope.

Comment: sadly, it didn't help me connect to android studio

Answer (score 0):

By default, Mac won't show up Android device, you need android file transfer agent for that. Download and install it from [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/androidjumper/mtp/current/AndroidFileTransfer.dmg).

Comment: Download Samsung PC suite and give it a try. I had same problem with MI device and installing MI PC Suite worked for me. Here is the link. https://www.samsung.com/in/support/kies/

Comment: it didn't help connect to android studio, sadly